# OMSimulator PreCompiled Binaries

Tags: openmodelica

I can find OMSimulator-Win 64 bit pre compiled binaries. Where can I find the OMSimulator-Win 32 bit pre-compiled binaries on the github?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852)

Comment: @DushyantTankariya It seems to me that this is a valid question. Not everyone speaks fluent English. Sure maybe the "best place" to ask this is the OpenModelica forums. However he will probably get faster responses here anyway.

Comment: yes @stardust I agree with your comment. The only purpose of my above statement is to improve his/her question quality. By reading his question seem to be off-topic please have a look [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) > **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** > Read 4th point Questions asking us to recommend or find a **software library** is off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit version of OMSimulator will not be build on every test. You can search for the latest test run on [OMSimulator Jenkins](https://test.openmodelica.org/jenkins/job/OMSimulator/job/master/) which did run the stage `mingw32-cross` (at the moment this would be [#337](https://test.openmodelica.org/jenkins/job/OMSimulator/job/master/337/)) and install with that artifacts.

**Second option:**
You can install 32-Bit OpenModelica on Windows, which comes along with OMSimulator. See the download-page from [Openmodelica.org](https://openmodelica.org/download/download-windows).

**Third option:**
You can build 32-bit version of OMSimulator on your machine to get it. See the install steps from the [README](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMSimulator#compilation). Compile it with [OMDev mingw](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMSimulator#windows-omdev-mingw) or [Visual Studio](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMSimulator#windows-visual-studio).